# Replace character before date match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace the underscore that precedes a date in a string e.g.

```
thequick_brown_20210813_fox
```

To:

```
thequick_brown_red_20210813_fox
```

I.e. replace that underscore with `_red_`

This captures the date part: `(20\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})`

And to replace I assume I can just use `str.replace`

But not sure how I can capture the underscore that precedes it.

Comment: _"But not sure how I can capture the underscore"_ - Add it to the regular expression and then replace the match with only the date. -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Use `/_(?=20\d{6}_)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following RegEx with Positive Lookahead:

```
/_(?=\d{8})/
```

**Where:**

`_`  matches the character `_`

`(?=\d{8})` - Positive Lookahead

`\d` - matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

`{8}` - matches the previous token exactly 8 times

```js
var str = 'thequick_brown_20210813_fox';
var patt = /_(?=\d{8})/;
str = str.replace(patt, '_red_');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: that's a lookahead :)

Comment: We've got almost identical solutions :) However I must confress I am allergic to `var` :)))))

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when it does not require that the 8-digit date begin with '20'?

Comment: @Booboo I see your point, however I adjusted the regex like so `_(?=20\d{6})` ....Which seems to work

Answer (score 1):

### This works

#### And as bonus I have a super robust regex for dates

```js
const str = 'thequick_brown_20210813_fox';
const re = /_(?=\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))/;
const newStr = str.replace(re, '_red_');
console.log(newStr);
```

The regex is [from here](https://regexland.com/regex-dates/)

Comment: That date regex is awesome! :D

Comment: Why is there bold text? What is OP supposed to do with _"This works"_? Why is the _"bonus"_ (copied from an external resouce) relevant for OP?

Comment: @apples-oranges Not really. A _"super robust"_ regex should also work with leap years. It's not more robust than a simple `_[0-9]{8}`...

Comment: @Andreas :))))))))))))))))

Comment: Unlike the OP's regex, this does not look for dates that start with '20', but should. Some bonus, eh.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk So it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using the RegEx you provided.

```js
let str = "thequick_brown_20210813_fox";
let newStr = "";
let regex = /(20\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;

let splits = str.split(regex);
newStr += splits[0] + "red_";
for(let i=1; i<splits.length; i++){
    newStr += splits[i];
}

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use as a matching regex:

```
_(?=20[0-9]{6})
```

1. `_` Matches underscore if ...
2. `(?=20[0-9]{6})` This is a lookahead assertion that the following characters must be '20' followed by 6 digits.

Note that the above only matches the underscore when followed by '20' followed by an additional 6 digits. So we simply replace the underscore with '_red_':

```js
let s = 'thequick_brown_20210813_fox';
s = s.replace(/_(?=20[0-9]{6})/g, '_red_');
console.log(s);
```